# Remove Elements of an array on an object based on outer object property

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I want to remove elements from one of its' properties that is an array of objects based on a matching property of the outer object.

This uses npm deep-diff to compare the two objects.

My problem is inside of combineDuplicateRecords it compares every record against every record, creating duplicates in the identities array.  So identities will end up looking like:

```
[{
    id: "111",
    identities: [
      {
        id: "111"
      },
      {
        id: "111"
      },
      {
        id: "222"
      },
      {
        id: "222"
      },
      {
        id: "333"
      },
      {
        id: "333"
      }
    ]
}]
```

when I really want it to look like this:

```
[{
id: "111",
identities:[
      {
        id: "222"
      },
      {
        id: "333"
      }
    ]
}]
```

Code:

```
var requestRecords = [
      {
        vid: "12345",
        id: "12345",
        email: "gft@test.com",
        firstName: "GrandFathering",
        lastName: "TestMN",
        postalCode: "55443-2410",
        phone: "123-456-7890",
        key: "1212"
      },
      {
        vid: "121212",
        id: "12222",
        email: "g233@test.com",
        firstName: "NoMatch",
        lastName: "NoMatchFound",
        postalCode: "43233-2410",
        phone: "123-456-7890",
        key: "121233"
      },
      {
        vid: "111",
        id: "111",
        email: "ffffft@test.com",
        firstName: "samebatch",
        lastName: "samebatch",
        postalCode: "5545",
        phone: "123-456-7890",
        key: "3333",
      },
      {
        vid: "222",
        id: "222",
        email: "ffffft@test.com",
        firstName: "samebatch",
        lastName: "samebatch",
        postalCode: "5545",
        phone: "123-456-7890",
        key: "4444",
      },
      {
        vid: "333",
        id: "333",
        email: "ffffft@test.com",
        firstName: "samebatch",
        lastName: "samebatch",
        postalCode: "5545",
        phone: "123-456-7890",
        key: "55",

      }
    ];


  combineDuplicateRecords = (arrayOfRecords, prefilter) => {
    const recordsToRemove = [];
    arrayOfRecords.forEach(firstRecord => {
      arrayOfRecords.forEach((secondRecord, index) => {
        if (
          firstRecord.firstName == secondRecord.firstName &&
          firstRecord.lastName == secondRecord.lastName &&
          firstRecord.dateOfBirth == secondRecord.dateOfBirth &&
          firstRecord.phone == secondRecord.phone &&
          firstRecord.postalCode == secondRecord.postalCode &&
          firstRecord.id !=
            secondRecord.id
        ) {
          const identities = [];
          let identity = {};
          this.preserveExisitingIdentities(secondRecord, identities);
          this.preserveExisitingIdentities(firstRecord, identities);
          identity = this.setIdentityDifferencesBetweenRecords(
            firstRecord,
            secondRecord,
            prefilter,
            identity
          );
          identities.push(identity);
          firstRecord["identities"] = identities;
          recordsToRemove.push(index);
        }
      });
    });

    [...new Set(recordsToRemove)].forEach(index => {
      arrayOfRecords.splice(index, 1);
    });
    return arrayOfRecords;
  };

    preserveExisitingIdentities = (record, identities) => {
    if (record.hasOwnProperty("identities")) {
      record.identities.forEach(identity => {
        identities.push(identity);
      });
    }
    return identities;
  };

    setIdentityDifferencesBetweenRecords = (
    firstIdentity,
    secondIdentity,
    prefilter,
    identity
  ) => {
    const differences = Diff(firstIdentity, secondIdentity, prefilter);
    let i = differences.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (differences[i].path[0] == "vid") {
        differences.splice(i, 1);
      }

      if (differences[i].path[0] == "identities") {
        differences.splice(i, 1);
      }
      //we only want to keep the differences so we remove kind D
      if (differences[i]?.kind == "D") {
        differences.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    differences.forEach(diff => {
      identity[diff.path[0]] = diff.lhs;
    });
    return identity;
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(combineDuplicateRecords(requestRecords)));
```

Comment: It looks like you've already done a ton of existing. Work. The easiest way to fix this with zero code modification is to just have a small algorithm to remove those duplicates based on the inner key. Do you need help writing it?

Comment: that'd be great. i'm also open to doing this a different way if there is a better approach and scrapping my initial idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grab each inner id and save them in a data structure, then use `Array#find` to find the entire object and insert it back into `identities`

```js
const array = [
{
    id: "111",
    identities: [
        {
            id: "111"
        },
        {
            id: "111"
        },
        {
            id: "222"
        },
        {
            id: "222"
        },
        {
            id: "333"
        },
        {
            id: "333"
        }
    ]
}
]

const cleanObject = (obj) => {
const allIds = obj.identities.map(({ id }) => id)
const mainId = obj.id
const uniqueIds = new Set(allIds)
uniqueIds.delete(mainId)

const nextIdentities = [...uniqueIds].map(currId => {
    return obj.identities.find(({ id }) => currId === id)
})
obj.identities = nextIdentities
return obj
};

const el = array.map(entry => {
return cleanObject(entry)
})

console.log(el)
```

Comment: i think id:111 should not be in inner array

Comment: In your first code snippet, that isn't valid javascript, so I made a few (wrong) assumptions as to what the structure is. Can you clean it up and show us _exactly_ what it is?

Comment: @JoshAdams My assumptions were correct on the data structure, but it was actually a mistake on my interpretation of the expected output (whoops). Updated.